# Swift - Make whole view controller vertically scrollable: have empty space at bottom safe area

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a `MainViewController` with some elements inside. I want the whole view to be vertically scrollable.
I made this `BaseScrollableViewController` class:

```
class BaseScrollableViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Then I made the `MainViewController` a subclass of this `BaseScrollableViewController`. Inside, I use `contentView` to add all the subviews.

Now it scrolls vertically. However, when I scroll down to the bottom, here is what is shows:

[image: Screenshot]

Note that there is **an empty space at the bottom**.

I have tried the `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`, but then the scrollView becomes **not scrollable**.

So how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the scroll working?, I'm asking this because you are setting the contentView height equal to the scrollView

Comment: The scroll is working. @Claudio

Answer (score 1):

For a scrollView to be scrollable, its subviews need to be bigger than the scrollView. By specifying the following constraint `contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)` on the `BaseScrollableViewController` you are specifying that the `contentView` will have the same height of the `scrollView`, thus making the view not scrollable when setting `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`.

You can test this by adding a multiplier value on the contentView height constraint:

```
contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.5)
```

And enabling

```
`scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have organized the view controller and I don't want to change it to stackview.